# Draw Straight Line Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

hey everyone I'm working on an iOS app and I integrated Google Maps API and I'm using Objective C

I implemented a function that put marks on the maps for every touch to the screen + I get the longitude and latitude of that mark

I want to draw straight lines between those marks, every time I add a new mark it should be linked with the one before

Any ideas please !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.0)];

GMSPolyline *line = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
line.map = mapView_;
```

Comment: it works thanks a lot but I used 
marker.draggable = YES;
so when I drag the marker the path doesn't change !!

Comment: You need to update path according it. And draw line.

Comment: I still didn't know how to update path
I know that it needs to be implemented in didEndDraggingMarker but i didn't know how

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ekta's answer: If you want to change the line when your Marker is dragged, you just need to follow these steps:

- Clear your map using `[mapview clear];`
- Redraw the line using directions given by Ekta.

Hope it helps.